Excel conditional formatting doesn't apply though formula returns TRUE
I am working with multiple data sets where a cell can have multiple values. I want to apply a conditional formatting on a cell with a formula to highlight the cell when it contains a keyword.
I have applied the below formula in conditional formatting, but it doesn't work. I have verified that the formula returns TRUE.
I want to highlight the cell if it contains "Red". Problem now is that it ONLY works if the return value "Red" is the first occurence.
=ISNUMBER(FIND("Red",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(H8,CHAR(10)),Activities!$B:$C,2,FALSE),""))))

Cell Value Example
Apple
Pear

Lookup Table Example that works:



Column B
Column C




Apple
Red


Pear
Green



Lookup Table Example that DOESN'T works:



Column B
Column C




Apple
Green


Pear
Red



Basically what I envisioned with the formula is:

To look up both Apple and Pear separately, TEXTSPLIT used in VLOOKUP
Once I got the results, merge back using TEXTJOIN
If the return value contains "Red", highlight the cell in red.

Any advise on this?

Edited the post to elaborate more on the problem and scenario.

The second argument to VLOOKUP() in your formula is Activities!$B:$C, which is two columns wide, but you are specifying column index 3 (for the third argument). Should this be 2?

@NeilT. my bad for the typo. I modified the formula values for simplicity, but missed the column index. I have edited the main post to reflect correctly.

Use XLOOKUP() instead of VLOOKUP(). Try =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Red",TEXTJOIN("|",1,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)),Activities!B:B,Activities!C:C)))). By the way your formula works fine to me.

@Harun24hr - are you sure the original formula works correctly, even if the first item in the list in H8 is something that's not present in the table? For me, the formula works if and only if the first item fits the criteria, as if the IFERROR/VLOOKUP combination is acting as a scalar formula instead of as an array formula.

I have the same problem as @NeilT. The formula works if the FIRST item satisfies the criteria, but doesn't work if "Red" is the second occurence.

@NeilT I have tested only with sample data. Let me check with different dat.

@NeilT So, it seems formula is not evaluating as array formula. I can remember, I read a article that said, dynamic spill array formula can't work as dynamic in CF rule. I have to check that article again.

Here's another one: =ISNUMBER(XMATCH("Red",XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)),Activities!$B$2:$B$3,Activities!$C$2:$C$3))). But they all won't work. Put either one in a new column and use that column with CF, e.g. =B2=TRUE.

highlight the cell when it contains a keyword Just wondering, why cannot you use COUNTIF with wildcards to check if the cell contains red?

Update 2024-09-14
Tested on a larger data set (~ 10,000, 30 in H8), filtering by 'Red' first, seems to work quickly on my Mac:
=SUM(N(FILTER(B1:B10000, C1:C10000 = "Red") = TEXTSPLIT(H8, CHAR(10)))) > 0



This is not what the OP is asking for. The requirement is that H8 itself should have conditional formatting applied (i.e. just one cell), to be highlighted if and only if the cell contains appropriate text. The "appropriate text" is not "Red", but rather an item in column B whose paired item in column C is "Red".

I think the intention is now correct, but the formula does not work correctly. One example: B3 = "Pear", C3 = "Green", B4 = "Apple", B5 = "Red", H5 contains "Carrot" and "Apple" (separated by a new line). I leave it to the OP to comment further.

The formula works in some sense, but for some reason, if I have more data set, and if the "Red" is the last occurence, the formula doesn't work anymore.
e.g. when the formula doesn't work. (Row 1 - Banana, Green) (Row 2 - Pear, Green) (Row 3 - Apple, Red)

hmmm. part of the formula doesn't work properly "((C1:C5 = "Red") > 0)". I got it to work by removing ">0". However, seems like the formula simply doesn't work in CF. Additionally, SUM is also taking a while to compute which may not satisfy my use case due to large datasets.

Thanks @nkalvi, the new formula works nicely. but for some reason the formula slows down the whole sheet once I applied in the CF. For performance improvement section, if a helper cell is used, an earlier workaround suggested by VBasic2008 to use formula in a different cell an do a "=B2=TRUE" in CF would've worked better.     As for the data size, Table B, C can go up to 10,000 rows, and I would have roughly 30 sets of H8.

@Arolix, please test the updated one when you get a chance - seems to work without any slowdown on my Mac with about 10k rows.

Not sure if I understood properly, but just in case I want to give it a shot:


Case 1: if target cell equals red then highlight adjacent cell

The formula of the CF rule is : =COUNTIF(C1;"Red")>0

Case 2: if any of the cells in target column equals red then highlight whole adjacent column

The formula of the CF rule is : =COUNTIF($C$6:$C$7;"red")>0
In both cases make sure the formula applies to whole fruits column
Both formulas will check if the cells is exactly the value red (without differentiating between uppercase and lowercase)
Also, please note CASE 2 works even if the value red is not in the first position of the column:


This is not what I'm looking for. Note that "Apple" and "Pear" should be in the SAME cell, in my case "H8". So if any of the lookup values of either "Apple" or "Pear" returns Red, the whole H8 cell should be highlighted.

Here's a link to my file on OneDrive to better understand the requirements. It also contains some of my attempts before (and after) I drew the conclusion described in OP's comments.

Yes the one use case depicted in your file is exactly what I envisioned, but the issue is the same where the formula would return TRUE, but it just simply doesn't work in CF. Similar to what you see in ID 7 and ID 9, where it contains Apple - "Red" but doesn't highlight the cell.

Try this:
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(H8, FILTER("*"&Activities!$B:$B&"*", Activities!$C:$C="Red", "#N/A")))>0

Using TextSplit to make a Dynamic Spill list of the items in cell H8 does not appear to function properly in a Conditional Formatting function.
However, using Filter on the Activities sheet does seem to work.
So, instead of checking each line in H8, finding its value in the Activities sheet, and then looking to see if that list contains "Red", we invert it:  We Filter to get the values from the Activities sheet that map to "Red", and then we check to see if any of those values exist in Cell H8.
(Note that this will, unfortunately, have issues with Substrings.  For example, if "Straw" is Red, but "Strawberry" is Green, then it will give a false-positive for "Strawberry", when it finds "Straw" at the start…)
{EDIT} The Substring issue was annoying me, so I decided to make things more rigorous:
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(H8, FILTER("*"&Char(10)&Activities!$B:$B&Char(10)&"*", Activities!$C:$C="Red", "#N/A"))+COUNTIF(H8, FILTER(Activities!$B:$B&Char(10)&"*", Activities!$C:$C="Red", "#N/A"))+COUNTIF(H8, FILTER("*"&Char(10)&Activities!$B:$B, Activities!$C:$C="Red", "#N/A"))+COUNTIF(H8, FILTER(Activities!$B:$B, Activities!$C:$C="Red", "#N/A")))>0

This will check for: contains the Activity value with a New Line at the start and end; starts with the Activity value followed by a New Line; ends with a New Line followed by the Activity value; or is exactly the Activity value.  That should eliminate any substrings.

Nice. This works!
But downside for me is that my dataset is continues to grow and the SUMPRODUCT just takes too long to evaluate the results.

Lookup table: M18:N19
Input table: I18:I19
Formula in K18 and drag down
If a  red marked fruit is in cell text return value is TRUE
=LET(inred,IF($N$18:$N$19="red",$M$18:$M$19,"ß"),
pos,IFERROR(FIND(inred,I18),0),
IF(SUM(pos)>0,TRUE,FALSE))


This is the screenshot of applying it on the sheet:


This has the same issue where the formula would return TRUE, but it just simply doesn't work in CF.

Pls. see the added screenshot of the formatting.
